# Skype Ubuntu internet connection problem

Tags: internet, skype

I installed Skype and it was working days before and working now in my android phone connected to same WIFI network but it can not connect to internet and only show this page:

[image]
and as you can see the setting option of it is disabled!!:

[image]

and the app installed form the Skype site don't detected for deleting by this command :

```
so@so-notebook:~$ sudo apt-get purge skype
[sudo] password for so: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for so: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "skype", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install skype"

E: Unable to locate package skype
so@so-notebook:~$ sudo apt-get remove skype skype-bin:i386 skype:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "skype", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install skype"

E: Unable to locate package skype
E: Unable to locate package skype-bin:i386
E: Unable to locate package skype:i386
so@so-notebook:~$
```

**Update:**
I have tried to update the skypeforlinux by synaptic package manager but during the installation Skype suddenly worked via Skype app and not working by chrome extension like this !!! :

[image]

and the task manger now is like this:

[image]

Thanks.